# jquery-barcode - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected Token }

Tags: jquery

I've been trying to code a Barcode clock in javascript, but an error keeps me away from using it. I click on the nameless button and then nothing happens. My console says Unexpected Token } and I haven't found the solution, why.

Oh, here's my URL to the page: [Page](http://bushcaliba.bplaced.net/clock/)

Also, here is my code:

```
<script src="jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-barcode.js"></script>
<script>
function timeGet() {
var today=new Date();
var hours=today.getHours();
var minutes=today.getMinutes();
var seconds=today.getSeconds();
minutes = checkTime(minutes);
seconds = checkTime(seconds);
var time = hours+":"+minutes+":"+seconds;
// document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = time;
}

function checkTime(i) {
if (i<10) {i = "0" + i};  // add zero in front of numbers < 10
return i;
}
</script>
```

[..]

```
<input class="button" type="button" onclick="$("#bcTarget").barcode(time, "ean13");">
```

And yes, I have a bcTarget div-container.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

don't use `"` inside a attribute if the attribute is surrounded with `"`.
your code on your html page should look like this

```
<input class="button" type="button" onclick="$('#bcTarget').barcode(time, 'ean13');">
```

Comment: "should look like this" --- also worth mentioning it's important to ensure that a next guy who will support this code doesn't know your physical address.

Comment: hate me for my english. i'm not a native english speaker

Comment: it has nothing to do with language. My point was that no one would write the code like you suggested. It's a terrible idea to put handler directly in html.

Comment: small suggestion to you - ``When you hear hoofbeats, think of horses not zebras`` sometimes it is better to give a simple answer then a complex one which confuses the asker much more

Comment: not sure how helping OP writing terrible code might make them a better developer. But it looks like you know what you do!

Comment: please make an answer with your suggestion or stop talk without telling the main point

Comment: `$('#button-id').click(...)`

Answer (score 0):

You should first fix this:

```
<input class="button" type="button" onclick="$("#bcTarget").barcode(time, "ean13");">
```

For this:

```
<input class="button" type="button" onclick='$("#bcTarget").barcode(time, "ean13");'>
```

Let me know if it changed something

Comment: Yes, that worked. Now this error is away. But now, it shows "time is not defined" Oh dear god, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: ``time is not defined`` describes that you don't have a ``variabel`` declared with the name ``time`` so js can't find it

Comment: Do you have your methods inside the $(document).ready() function?